# Image won't update in MySQL using PHP script

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, upload

I have an issue:

I'm working on a edit my account page on a website.

I'm writing a PHP script to update a user's image (type longBLOB).

It is not working however.

Here is my PHP script:

```
//db connection;

//PHP script that supposed to update image in mySQL is as follows
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if (!isset($file))
    echo 'Please select an image';
else {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size == FALSE)
        echo 'That is not an image';
    else {
        $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO people (Image) VALUES ('$image')");
    }


}
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form name="profileedit" action="updatedatabase.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '" method="post"     ectype="multipart/form-data"> 

<label style="padding-left:3em"> Image: </label> <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value=""> </input> <br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn_red"/>

</form>
```

**Please help!**

Comment: *Groan,* typo => `ectype` - change it to `enctype` and *MAGIC* will happen.

Comment: is there a particular reason you're storing the picture in the DB as opposed to on the server?

Comment: Fred -ii- : Thanks for typo correction. But it still isn't working.

Comment: serakfalcon: storing in db is equal to store it in the server.

Comment: You're welcome. Now this `action="updatedatabase.php?id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '"` - you do have `session_start();` loaded right? What does your HTML source reveal for the action?

Comment: yes i do have session_start(); I'm able to edit and update other fields such as first name, last name, etc. But not the picture.

Comment: What's the data type of your Image column?

Comment: Try with mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: An Phan : it's currently longblob

Comment: Paolo : What do you mean ?? The connection to the DB isn't the issue. I wrote it at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Might be silly, but try `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes()` on the image data.

Comment: An : No, it doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to update user's image, but all your script does is INSERTing of said image. You need to handle update action in your script too. For that, you also need id of the user because you need to pair image with user in database.

Something like this is supposed to be in your script:

`mysqli_query("UPDATE people SET Image='$image' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);`

Comment: Yes you are correct, I'm able to solve my question. I will post it later. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

There 2 problems in the PHP script:
1. mysqli_query requires 2 parameters.
2. The sql statements should be UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO.

Here is the correct PHP script :

```
//PHP script that supposed to update image in mySQL is as follows
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if (!isset($file))
echo 'Please select an image';
else {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size == FALSE)
        echo 'That is not an image';
     else {
         $result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE people SET Image='$image' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
     }
}
```

**Thank you all for the responses!!!**